# Make button disappear permanently

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a situation, when the user clicks a button in page A the button will disappear and go to page B. and when the user goes back to page A, the button will still disappear. Is it possible to do this? Is this sounds logical?

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>Booking Number</th>
            <th>checkin</th>
            <th>checkout</th>
            <th>Num. of days</th>
            <th>Total Charges</th>
            <th>Breakfast</th>
            <th>accommodation ID</th>
        </tr>
    <c:forEach items="${books}" var="book">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${book.bookingnum}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${book.checkin}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${book.checkout}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${book.numofdays}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${book.totalcharges}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${book.bfast}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${book.accid}" /></td>
                <td>
                <form name="reserveSubmitForm" method="post" action="Payment1Controller?action=createPayment&bookingnum=<c:out value="${book.bookingnum}"/>">
                <input  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Pay">onclick="style.display = 'none'"
                <input type="hidden" name="totalcharges" id="totalcharges" value="${book.totalcharges}"/>
                </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Comment: You may use cookies

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: I think you'll have to provide a little more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the button is clicked, you can set a value in `sessionStorage`. Also, on page load, check to see whether that value exists in `sessionStorage`, and if it does, hide the button. For example:

```
<a href="foo">foo</a>
```

JS:

```
const a = document.querySelector('a');
if (sessionStorage.clickedA) a.style.display = 'none';
a.addEventListener('click', () => {
  sessionStorage.clickedA = 'clicked';
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qfsuLyc3/

I don't think cookies are a good idea because it's information that seems to be only relevant for the client, not the server. (cookies will be sent to the server)

`sessionStorage` persists over a page session. If you want the button to be hidden even after the browser is reopened, use `localStorage` instead, which uses the file system, rather than memory, and is persistent.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :D Based on your example, if I want to use localStorage, so I can just change the sessionStorage to localStorage?

Comment: Yep, just replace the two `sessionStorage`s with `localStorage`

Comment: I've got another question, " a.addEventListener('click', () => " what does () and => means? because when I put the code in script.js, it shows error. It says:Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token "(", Expression expected after 
  this token
 - Syntax error on token ">", invalid 
  FunctionExpressionHeader

Comment: Sounds like you're using an obsolete browser that doesn't support ES2015. Switch to something more modern, ideally, but if you can't, use a standard function instead: `'click'', function() { ...` You can use Babel to automatically translate ES6+ syntax to ES5.

Comment: Wow.. Never heard of that before. Thank you so much, Sir! :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want this on a temporary basis, you can use **GET** method. You can pass an additional value in the URL from page two to page one, and check if the value is present or not.

Example:

```
<a href="pageOne.php?movingback=true">Go To Page One</a>
```

On the first page, check the presence of the **movingback** (I am using php to do the same)

```
<?php if(!isset($_GET['movingback']) || !$_GET['movingback']=='true'){
  echo "<a href='pagetwo.php'>Go To Page Two</a>"
}
```